# Unable to set_select for multiple select form element

Tags: codeigniter

```
<select multiple name="skills[]">
    <option value=".NET">.Net<?php echo set_select('skills[]', '.NET'); ?></option>
    <option value="JAVA">Java<?php echo set_select('skills[]', 'JAVA'); ?></option>
    <option value="php">PHP<?php echo set_select('skills[]', 'php'); ?></option>
    <option value="cloud">Cloud<?php echo set_select('skills[]', 'cloud'); ?></option>
</select></td>
```

Hello here I am trying to set_select() for select multiple but not able to do. Need help, how Can I do that.. Thanks.

Sorry but tried following code it is working, :)

```
<select multiple name="skills[]">
      <option value=".NET"<?php echo set_select('skills', '.NET'); ?>>.Net</option>
      <option value="JAVA"<?php echo set_select('skills', 'JAVA'); ?>>Java</option>
      <option value="php"<?php echo set_select('skills', 'php'); ?>>PHP</option>
      <option value="cloud"<?php echo set_select('skills', 'cloud'); ?>>Cloud</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by specifying the third parameter of set_select, if set to TRUE it sets an item as default. For selecting all the options in your example just try the following code:

```
<select name="myselect[]" multiple>
 <option value="one" <?php echo set_select('myselect', 'one', TRUE); ?> >One</option>
 <option value="two" <?php echo set_select('myselect', 'two',TRUE); ?> >Two</option>
 <option value="three" <?php echo set_select('myselect', 'three',TRUE); ?> >Three</option>
</select>
```

See info [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html)